# Prototype Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Tags: magento, prototypejs

The Chrome console is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

I search that line and found this:

```
  function _createResponder(element, eventName, handler) {
    var registry = Element.retrieve(element, 'prototype_event_registry');

    if (Object.isUndefined(registry)) {
      CACHE.push(element);
      registry = Element.retrieve(element, 'prototype_event_registry', $H());
    }
    var respondersForEvent = registry.get(eventName);
```

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined*

```
 if (Object.isUndefined(respondersForEvent)) {
      respondersForEvent = [];
      registry.set(eventName, respondersForEvent);
    }
```

Comment: You don't check if registry is still undefined. The second attempt to retrieve() the registry seems to fail too.

Comment: Look this thread : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/br/errors.php/viewthread/269153/ its the same case, but i dont know how to resolve..

Comment: I already comment all the code which recommend on the post i say before , this is the code which i disabled with <!-- and --> : http://forum.azmagento.com/magento-folder-structure/magento-app-files-app-design-frontend-base-default-template-catalogsearch-formminiphtml-10810.html and still the error

Comment: @MarkAnthon I am also facing same issue which you posted.Have you found any solution for this? Please suggest if yes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening when a "null" element is passed to the function on an event binding.  Try adding the following before the second line (var registry = ...)

```
if (element === null) return;
```

This will basically prevent any further processing within this function, which should not be necessary when the element is null.

I haven't found any issue with doing this on Magento, but please let me know if there is any problem with using this fix.